# Explaination needed for Accesschk output

Tags: windows, service, user-permissions

Can anybody explain permissions for all levels given below? 
I used accesschk to check the permissions of WAMPSERVER 3.0.6 installed on Win-7. If I run accesschk from it's folder I get following output:-

```
D:\tools>accesschk64.exe -ucqw wampapache64

Accesschk v6.02 - Reports effective permissions for securable objects
Copyright (C) 2006-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

wampapache64
  RW NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  RW BUILTIN\Administrators
```

But when I run it with absolute path, it gives following output:-

```
C:\Users\user>D:\tools\accesschk64.exe -ucqv wampapache64

Accesschk v6.02 - Reports effective permissions for securable objects
Copyright (C) 2006-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

wampapache64
  Medium Mandatory Level (Default) [No-Write-Up]
  RW NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
        SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS
  RW BUILTIN\Administrators
        SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS
  R  NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
        SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS
        SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG
        SERVICE_INTERROGATE
        SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS
        SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL
        READ_CONTROL
  R  NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE
        SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS
        SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG
        SERVICE_INTERROGATE
        SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS
        SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL
        READ_CONTROL
```

The output obtained by using absolute path of Accesschk adds up much more output. Why this is so? And what are the meanings of additional terms in the output?

Thanks
Kriss

Comment: The difference is because you've specified `-w` in the first example and `-v` in the second one.

Comment: oops, I didn't notice it lol.

Comment: Anybody on the explanation of extra information?

Comment: They're pretty self-explanatory, I'd have thought.  SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS gives you the right to query the status of the service, for example.  [Documentation is here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981(v=vs.85).aspx)